# Meaning of code in custom Mod_menu override

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0, joomla1.7

I am just creating a custom mod_menu in Joomla 3

I wonder if anyone could be so kind and explain what this block of code means since I can not find any reference to the parameter $item->params->get('aliasoptions) also what does this block of code actually do to the menu item? - (line 37 - code taken from default.php in tmpl folder from mod_menu)

```php
    $aliasToId = $item->params->get('aliasoptions');
    if (count($path) > 0 && $aliasToId == $path[count($path) - 1])
    {
        $class .= ' active';
    }
    elseif (in_array($aliasToId, $path))
    {
        $class .= ' alias-parent-active';
    }
```

Any explanation to this would be most helpful, I am wondering if it's actually needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats the corresponding function from the helper.php

```
case 'alias':
// If this is an alias use the item id stored in the parameters to make the link.
$item->flink = 'index.php?Itemid=' . $item->params->get('aliasoptions');
break;
```

So if you look at the function in default.php you will see this piece of code:

```
foreach ($list as $i => &$item) :
$class = 'item-'.$item->id;
```

and following with an if clause and after that the code you are asking for.

So what it basically does (in my understanding):
Use the item id defined in itemparameters (basically its just the item id xD ) if the link is just an alias for another menu item. Without it Joomla shouldnt be able to set the correct active menu links.
You can set Menu Item Aliases by choosing them in the Menu Item Type selection: "System Links -> Menu Item Alias", when creating or editing menu items ;)

I hope this helps ^^

Comment: Hi Django, thanks for the heads up I was not looking hard enough for this parameter which rightly so was in Menu Item Type selection: "System Links -> Menu Item Alias" now it makes clear sense in that it only becomes active when selected that's why I could not see it when I did a var_dump on the menu. - Thanks again.